# URL.Action with a string array?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I have an array of strings that I need to pass in a query string of Url.Action.

```
Url.Action("Index", "Resource", new { FormatIds = Model.FormatIDs})
```

Right now the link is showing up in my browser as System.String[] instead of a query string.  Is it possible to have MVC do this automatically with model binding?

I need it to bind with my controller action like:

```
public ActionResult Index(string[] formatIDs)
```

Comment: what do you expect the output to look like?

Comment: I need it to bind with my controller action that looks like:  

public ActionResult Index(string[] formatIDs)

Comment: a query string generally isn't the best way to do this.

Answer (score 11):

To get the list of string to automatically bind using the default binder, you will need to provide them as:

```
name=value&name=value2&name=value3
```

So you'll need to convert your list to something like:

```
Index?formatIDs=1&formatIDs=2&formatIDs=3
```

Comment: +1 for the default model binder, that is the correct anwser. Very Nice Queti.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He wants Url.Action to correctly output an array route value to the querystring. He is not asking how to bind such a value.

Answer (score 9):

For use the default model binder, you should end up with something like :

```
Index?formatIDs=value1&formatIDs=value2&formatIDs=value3
```

you can returns a private collection named HttpValueCollection even the documentation says it's a NameValueCollection using the ParseQueryString utility. 
Then add the keys manually, HttpValueCollection do the encoding for you.
And then just append the QueryString manually :

```
var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(""); 
new string[] { "value1", "value2", "value3" }.ToList().ForEach(x => qs.Add("formatIDs", x));

Url.Action("Index", "Resource")?@qs
```

Comment: Your suggestion works. But I wonder why it's still so strange and complex to send an array of strings from a razor View to a MVC controller action.

Comment: Because normally you should use a form HTML element with get verb and everything will be smooth and simple.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way using the RouteValueDictionary with an array:

```
@{
   var parameters = new RouteValueDictionary();

   for (var i = 0; i < Model.CustomList.Count; ++i)
   {
       parameters.Add($"customListId[{i}]", Model.CustomList[i]);
   }
}
```

usage:

```
var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ControllerActioon", "Controller", parameters))';
```

Still not very elegant - but working.