# Multi-value GET parameters - route generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When using multi-value GET parameters like so:

```
/?param=1&param=2&param=3
```

You can automatically model-bind to a list, like so:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(List<int> param)
```

How can I pass such values using anonymous types, in URL generation?

```
@Url.Action("MyAction", new { param = ?? })
```

Using an array / list **doesn't** work -

```
@Url.Action("MyAction", new { param = new List<string>{ "1", "2", "3" } })
```

As it just spits out `Object.ToString()` like:

```
?param=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.String%5D
```

Cheers

Comment: Don't use inline initialization, that's your mistake.

Comment: I've tried both (and it makes no difference, progmatically)

Comment: @AndreiV: I understand your comment, but don't get why this makes a difference. Can you explain?

Comment: What does the route setup look like?

Comment: What about a custom ModelBinder or RouteService? I can't find a solution and have been working on it previously.

Comment: I've had a play and look around, and I think you're doomed to have to manually construct the query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the nice solution your after, buy you could do, assuming you know whether to add the ? or not.

```
@Url.Action("MyAction")?param=@string.Join("&param=", new [] {1, 2, 3})
```

Maybe a helper could be written that does this. see [URL.Action with a string array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887570/url-action-with-a-string-array)