# ASP.NET MVC 3 RouteUrl with two parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to build URL in razor view that will pass 2 RouteData.Values to my action.
This is my code in view:

```
    <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("CompleteFrameBrand", new { groupId = group.Id, groups = Model.Groups })"><img src="@("../../Themes/Pac/Content/images/" + group.Id + ".png")" style="vertical-align: middle; max-height: 120px; max-width: 340px;" alt="logo"/></a>
```

This is code in controller:

```
    public ActionResult CompleteFrameBrand(string groupId, List<PacNopGroup> groups)
```

and this is my route provider:

```
    routes.MapLocalizedRoute("CompleteFrameBrand",
            "pacmodule/completeglass/{groupId}",
            new { controller = "PacCompleteFrame", action = "CompleteFrameBrand" },
            new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

In view I have 9 Items in Model.Groups. But when I pass it to new controller it counts 0. Even if I pass hwole model I get null in controller. Can someone explain me how should I correctly pass model object from view to controller through Url.RouteUrl. 
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi-value GET parameters - route generation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605430/multi-value-get-parameters-route-generation)

Comment: it is not duplication. if i have both param as string i get it corectly to the controller. but if one is object with list inside this list become empty in controller. don't know why :(

Comment: yeah - because the route generation is wrong - see the solution in the answer I posted

Comment: You seem to be passing a collection of complex types on the querystring. Have you thought about using TempData, or persisting to cookie / session instead?